# Jackson JSON converts integers into strings

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using the object mapper to map into an object that has String variables. This works a little too well, because even integers and booleans from the JSON are converted into Strings.
Example:

```
{"my_variable":123}

class MyClass{
    String my_variable;
}
```

I would like the object mapper to report an error in this kind of situation instead of converting 123 into a string for my_variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Report an error?Why not an exception?: )

Comment: exception would be great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no such configuration, but you can override default deserializer with a custom one (see [fasterxml wiki](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers)) and make that throw an exception?

If you would like a more convenient way you can file a Jira enhancement request; for example, new `DeserializationConfig.Feature.COERCE_STRINGS_AS_NUMBERS` (default to true) that one could disable to prevent such coercion.