# How to avoid string to number conversion for doubles and numbers expressed in Scientific Notation?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, scientific-notation

I receive `JSON` payload which is set of key-value pairs. Value may be either string or number. I have to parse the `JSON` and store key-value pairs into appropriate `varchar2` columns. I should save incoming number **exactly as it was presented in the input payload**. 
But for numbers presented like `1.1E4`, `0.00000000000003` and similar I get `11000.0`, `3.0E-14` instead.

Is it a way to disable/prevent number conversion to have just string representation instead?

I use `FasterXML` `Jackson` implementation.
By the way there is no actual doc available - all sources I found point to http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome which is down right now.
I found two similar questions here
[Jackson JSON converts integers into strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806316/jackson-json-converts-integers-into-strings)
[Disable the Number to String automatic conversion in jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678885/disable-the-number-to-string-automatic-conversion-in-jackson)
but both require exception when encounter number, which is not my case. I have tried suggested solutions but was unsuccessful in modifying them to fit my task.

Also there is no answer in
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/796

Right now I have no specification for input string other than key-value pairs. So just an example:

I **may** receive something like:

```
{"a":"text", "b":"35", "c":{"d":"another"}, "e":["array",35], "f":1.1E4, "g":0.00000000000003}
```

I want string pairs

```
"a" -> "text", "b" -> "35", "c" -> "{\"d\":\"another\"}", "e" -> "[\"array\",35]", "f" -> "1.1E4"
```

The simplest conversion way is:

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    Map map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(
    "{\"a\":\"text\", \"b\":\"35\", \"c\":{\"d\":\"another\"}, \"e\":[\"array\",35], \"f\":1.1E4, \"g\":0.00000000000003}"
        , Map.class);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

results in:

```
{a=text, b=35, c={d=another}, e=[array, 35], f=11000.0, g=3.0E-14}
```

The more accurate way:

```
public class JsonUtil2 {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static Map<String, String> parse(String json) throws IOException {
        ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) OBJECT_MAPPER.readTree(json);

        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>(objectNode.size());
        objectNode.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> result.put(entry.getKey(), toJson(entry.getValue())));
        return result;
    }

    private static String toJson(JsonNode jsonNode) {
        if (jsonNode.isNumber()) {
            if (jsonNode instanceof DoubleNode || jsonNode instanceof FloatNode) {
                DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
                dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
                dfs.setMinusSign('-');
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#", dfs);
                df.setMaximumFractionDigits(32);
                df.setMaximumIntegerDigits(32);
                return df.format(jsonNode.doubleValue());
            } else {
                return jsonNode.asText();
            }
        } else if (jsonNode.isValueNode()) {
            return jsonNode.asText();
        } else {
            try {
                return OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which results in:

```
{a=text, b=35, c={"d":"another"}, e=["array",35], f=11000, g=0.00000000000003}
```

This is much better, but still differ in `f=11000` instead of `f=1.1E4`.

Comment: Please show your JSON string and how you parse it!

Comment: You could use `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @MC Emperor, What I need is to store parsed key-value pairs in DB as strings. How could I use BigDecimal for that?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you want to treat everything as a `String`, so you need a custom deserialiser which reads `JSON Object` and `JSON Array` as `String`. We can also force `Jackson` to read `Map<String, String>` by providing this information using `TypeFactory`.

Assume our `JSON` payload looks like below:

```
{
  "a": "text",
  "b": "35",
  "c": {
    "d": "another",
    "dd":3.44E3
  },
  "e": [
    "array",
    35,
    2.3E5
  ],
  "f": 1.1E4,
  "g": 0.00000000000003
}
```

Example code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.CollectionType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonTreeApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        SimpleModule everythingIsStringModule = new SimpleModule();
        everythingIsStringModule.addDeserializer(String.class, new EverythingIsStringDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(everythingIsStringModule);

        MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(LinkedHashMap.class, String.class, String.class);

        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, mapType);
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " => " + v));
    }
}

class EverythingIsStringDeserializer extends StringDeserializer {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        if (p.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            return _deserializeFromObject(p, ctxt);
        }
        return super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
    }

    private String _deserializeFromObject(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        MapType mapType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(LinkedHashMap.class, String.class, String.class);
        JsonDeserializer<Object> deserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(mapType);
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) deserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);

        return toString(map);
    }

    @Override
    protected String _deserializeFromArray(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        CollectionType collectionType = ctxt.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, String.class);
        JsonDeserializer<Object> deserializer = ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(collectionType);
        List<String> list = (List<String>) deserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);

        return toString(list);
    }

    private String toString(Map<String, String> map) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(128);

        builder.append('{');
        boolean addComa = false;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (addComa) {
                builder.append(',');
            }
            builder.append('"').append(entry.getKey())
                    .append("\":");
            appendValue(entry.getValue(), builder);
            addComa = true;
        }
        builder.append('}');

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String toString(List<String> list) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(128);

        builder.append('[');
        boolean addComa = false;
        for (String item : list) {
            if (addComa) {
                builder.append(',');
            }
            appendValue(item, builder);
            addComa = true;
        }
        builder.append(']');

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private void appendValue(String value, StringBuilder builder) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            builder.append("\"\"");
            return;
        }
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(value.charAt(0))) {
            builder.append('"').append(value).append('"');
        } else {
            builder.append(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
a => text
b => 35
c => {d=another, dd=3.44E3}
e => [array, 35, 2.3E5]
f => 1.1E4
g => 0.00000000000003
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is much better. But using this way I still get 
`c => {d=another, dd=3.44E3}` 
instead of  
`c => {"d:"another", "dd":3.44E3}`

Is it a way to improve in such way?

Comment: @Roman, You would have to implement your own `JSON Object` deserialisation. In `_deserializeFromObject` method you can read all tokens manually and build it using `StringBuilder`. Or, after reading `Map` you can iterate over all `key-value` pairs and wrap them into quotes.

Comment: @Roman, have you fixed that problem with wrapping key-value pairs for objects?

Comment: @Michael Zlobin, thank you again, could you provide a sample how to implement AbstractDeserializer in such a way?